# Using node.js to contact SQL database erroring

Tags: node.js, database

I have a node.js script that contacts my SQL database and puts the data on a json page so I can read it with applications.`const

```
express = require('express');

const mysql = require('mysql2');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3306;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({

  host: 'localhost',

  user: 'person',

  password: 'aerocks',

  database: 'databaseae'

});

db.connect()

app.get('/players', (req, res) => {

  db.query('SELECT * FROM players', (err, results) => {

    if (err) {

      throw err;

    }

    res.send(results);

  });

});

app.post('/players', (req, res) => {

  const userId = req.body.UserId;

  db.query('INSERT INTO players (UserId) VALUES (?)', [userId], (err, result) => {

    if (err) {

      throw err;

    }

    res.send('Player added to database');

  });

});

app.listen(port, () => {

  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);

});
```

That's my node script (this is in repl)

```
CREATE DATABASE databaseae;

USE databaseae;

CREATE USER 'person'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'aerocks';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databaseae.* TO 'person'@'localhost';

CREATE TABLE players (

  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

  UserId BIGINT NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO players (UserId) VALUES (3945395184),(3260802249),(3013832163),(603938760),(3117657753),(1412301409),(3139784258),(2410006095),(2891511025),(1152703907),(3311103113),(3320131875),(1857899695),(3013832163),(3022822700),(3053889447),(3184079680),(3709088363),(2031717628),(272548471),(687108206),(3094619583),(3586441632),(2299363932),(1158686192),(59442382),(1623159899),(3537849954),(3359337023),(1814631082),(3258718308),(197380889),(10995525),(3458118723),(1891202158),(3257889681),(3335725268);
```

Can someone please help me squash the error?

I tried rewriting the database, changing passwords, reinstalling SQL, I expected it to work completely fine, but what resulted was that it kept erroring and would just kill repl. Maybe I did something wrong?
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS3b9.png)

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: @lpizzinidev https://prnt.sc/Yldfse1G-Zwz

Comment: Are you running all of this on your local machine, or are you perhaps running this on a web IDE that's on a different computer?

Comment: I am using this on a web IDE, I am using repl.it to host this.